# Sending email with images with Elastic email's API and Laravel

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.3

I've implemented a Laravel plugging https://packagist.org/packages/comyoo/laravel-elastic-email

But when I receive the emails they are all without images, of course before the implementation was correctly working (custom smtp)

I'm using the Elastic Email API (Free)
Laravel 5.3. 
And the code:

`src="{{ $message->embed(url('/templates/frontend/img/web/logomail.png')) }}"`

to embed the images into the email.

Any one knows what should I check to make it work?
Is the plugin's problem? Elastic email's API? Or should I change embed to another option?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that script and the problem is with `$message->embed(` try sourcing the images with `src="{{url('/` that way will work correctly. Additionally just make sure the source is public online.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the plugin company:

Thanks for contacting us. What does the source code of recieved mail shows?
No url? or bad url? 
This is how we implement assets based on themes.

And is your image in the 'public' folder of Laravel?